# Help with an iPad iBookstore-like Interface

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ibooks

I am building an iPad application that needs to list books in a manner similar to the way Apple does it in their iBookstore application and how Marvel does it in their iPad application. I'm not talking about the main featured rotating images but rather the book listing below that.

My question is looking at the book list, how are they being displayed? Is a series of sub-classed UIViews or a custom UITableViewCell? Or is it something else altogether different?

Thank you in advance for any help.

L.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AQGridView](http://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView). (That's not what iBooks is using, but it achieves the same effect)

Comment: AWESOME! Thank you for responding so quickly. I think this will do the  trick. Thanks again!

Comment: Dave, have you used AQGridView before? I'm having one problem: how do you handle a grid cell selection? I can't figure it out.